# send custom expected Deleivery date into fedex api with magento

Tags: php, magento, fedex

I am working on Magento and FedEx integration. I successfully integrated FedEx and Magento using [ShipSync](http://www.illapps.com/). But FedEx take departure date as the same date when order has been placed. So is there any way to send custom departure date or expected delivery date so we can customize the delivery date module.

Answer (score 0):

ShipSync would need to be adjusted to allow for a custom ship or ground home date certain delivery date.